# Problema con resultado de una consulta en mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Realizo la siguiente consulta, para ser mostrado en una tabla.

```
$qry= "select  round(b.monto_final_adelantado*100/sum(a.monto) ) as por 
       from fc_facturas a inner join rc_proyectos b on a.id_proyecto = 
       b.id_proyecto where b.id_proyecto =".$idpro;
$stmt = $bd->ejecutar($qry);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt,MYSQLI_BOTH);
$prc = $row['por'];
return $prc;
```

En mysql workbench me da el resultado correcto, sin embargo al mostrar el resultado por php/html me returna solo "0".

Comment: Si `id_proyecto` es numérico, escribe tu consulta así: **`$qry="select  round(b.monto_final_adelantado*100/sum(a.monto) ) as por 
       from fc_facturas a inner join rc_proyectos b on a.id_proyecto = 
       b.id_proyecto where b.id_proyecto = $idpro";`**, y asegúrate que `$idpro` tiene el valor que crees que tiene.

Comment: Intenta añadir algo más de información: ¿cómo corres la consulta en Workbench?¿qué resultado obtienes ahí? ¿Cómo muestras los datos en PHP?¿qué resultado obtienes?

Comment: También has un echo a la variable $idpro y asegúrate que esté trayendo el valor deseado

Comment: lo intento mostrar asi en el index.php.

dentro de un while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($stmt,MYSQLI_BOTH))

<td><?php echo getPorcentaje($row['id_proyecto']);?></td>